# Unable to do pandas profiling and generating report in notebook

Tags: python, report, typeerror, vbox, pandas-profiling

This is the error which I always get. The vbox error comes in my both auto viz and profiling report. Please let me know if my notebook is outdated or where I am missing the part ?

**

```
type of the return value must be pandas_profiling.report.presentation.core.renderable.Renderable; got ipywidgets.widgets.widget_box.VBox instead
```

**

I was trying to generate the profiling report automated version for exploratory data analysis .The code I used is written below: :

1. import sys

   !{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]

   !jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

2. from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report")

3.profile.to_widgets()

Comment: you have posted the error message, but the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the whole code below too